# Оверлей для любой программы и игры DirectX в фуллскрине через инжект dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет.
Хочу сделать универсальный оверлей, который при запуске из консольного приложения будет инжектить dll с самим оверлеем в любую программу, как у стима/дискорда.
Про инжект dll я знаю, а вот про сам dll нет.

Подскажите, как можно создать в dll "точку входа" тем самым запустить графический интерфейс (желательно написанный на wpf)?

Видел много туториалов с windows forms. Но они не подходят. Для игры в фуллскрине DirecX ничего не отобразится, да и задержка у перемещения окна большая.

Comment: На инжект может сработать античит. Поэтому лишний раз подумайте что вам нужно: лишний раз получить возможность попасть в бан или переключить игру в "оконный полноэкранный" режим куда без инжектов вставляется оверлей.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Мне нужен именно инжект. Большинство нормальных античитов не реагируют на простой инжект, они реагируют на считывание/изменение памяти, а таких махинаций не будет

Comment: Вы не сможете обойтись без изменения памяти. Так что ваша программа однозначно будет восприниматься как чит. И вы не сможете так просто подключить WPF формы. Потому что в полноэкранном режиме нет никаких окон. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925981/overlaying-on-a-3d-fullscreen-application

Comment: @Zergatul Даже если так, то я хотя бы хочу посмотреть хоть какой-нибудь пример с инжектом

Comment: Я боюсь, вам нужно для начала сменить язык на тот, который позволяет собирать неуправляемые модули. Вы не можете инжектировать DLL на C# в любой процесс, так как процесс не обязан иметь загруженную CLR необходимой версии; а попытка загрузить CLR насильно может нарушить его работу.